# Android ROOM - Kotlin - Insert return value with multiple parameters of different type

Tags: kotlin, android-room

With Insert Room datbase, I need insert two entity at one time.

```
@Transaction
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertChemicalChemistry(baseChemical: BaseChemical, langInfo: LanguageComplimentChemical?): List<Long>
```

I read the documentation on the android developer site
[text](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert)
This is allowed

However, when my project build one exception throw in build output:

> Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

I try change the type return like Long, Map, other but not complete. I hope everyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is have something along the lines of:-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(baseChemical: BaseChemical): Long
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(langInfo: LanguageComplimentChemical): Long

@Transaction
@Query("")
/*suspend*/ fun insertChemicalChemistry(baseChemical: BaseChemical, langInfo: LanguageComplimentChemical?): List<Long> {
    val rv1 = insert(baseChemical)
    var rv2: Long = -1
    if (langInfo != null) {
        rv2 = insert(langInfo)
    }
    return listOf(rv1,rv2)
}
```

This when you want to insert the pair of entities you would use `insertChemicalChemistry`

- Note suspend removed for the demo
- the `@Query("")` is used to fool Room into considering the function should be run within a transaction. Without, *unless things have changed*, the function would not be run within a transaction.

You could also have the freedom to insert the entities individually using the respective `insert` function.

Consider the following demo:-

```
    val bc = BaseChemical(null,"BC001","blah")
    val lc = LanguageComplimentChemical(name = "LC001", etc = "more blah")

    dao.insert(bc)
    dao.insert(lc)
    val result1 = dao.insertChemicalChemistry(bc,lc)
    val result2 = dao.insertChemicalChemistry(bc,null)
    val brkpnt = result1.get(0) + (result1.get(1) * 1024)
```

- where the last line has a break point

When run in debug mode then the result when the breakpoint is reached is:-

[image]

As can be seen:-

- result1 has 2 values both of which are 2. That is, both the insert functions return the id field (as they are an alias of the rowid column) which is generated.
- result2 has a value of 3 for the first value of the pair, the id of the BaseChemical and therefore it was inserted. However, the second value is -1, indicating that either a null LanguageComplimentChemical was passed (as was the case), or that the row was not inserted.

  - you could change `var rv2: Long = -1` to use another value if you wanted to differentiate between an ignored insert and a null LanguageComplimentChemical.

Comment: My intention is one is to insert all, the other is to have no objects inserted. My aim is to get the transaction for the whole. However, each ROOM @insert statement already has a transaction, so wrapping a parent transaction doesn't guarantee that when an inserted object fails, all previous inserts must be rolled back.

Comment: So inserting 2 objects at the same time is wrapped by ROOM in one transaction, but I can't know the return result, it's annoying if I customize an insert function. I tried to find another way similar to yours. Thank you very much.

Comment: @VIL the return result, as was shown in the example is returned (i.e. the breakpoint) . The result can be whatever you want and are able to build. Perhaps you should edit your question to show the `@Entity` annotated classes, and an example of data to be inserted and your expectation of the result the example data would return. Obviously covering all the expected scenarios.